# How to request a page with a specific charset in Go?

Tags: http, go

I am rewriting a software from Python to Go. I am facing an issue with the `http.Get` while fetching a page encoded in `iso-8859-1`. The Python version is working but not the one in Go.

This is working: Python

```
r = requests.get("https://www.bger.ch/ext/eurospider/live/de/php/aza/http/index.php?lang=de&type=show_document&print=yes&highlight_docid=aza://27-01-2016-5A_718-2015")
r.encoding = 'iso-8859-1'
file = open('tmp_python.txt', 'w')
file.write(r.text.strip())
file.close()
```

This is not working: Go

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/net/html/charset"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    link := "https://www.bger.ch/ext/eurospider/live/de/php/aza/http/index.php?lang=de&type=show_document&print=yes&highlight_docid=aza://27-01-2016-5A_718-2015"
    resp, err := http.Get(link)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    reader, err := charset.NewReader(resp.Body, "iso-8859-1")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(content))
}
```

My browser and Python give the same result but not the Go version. How can I fix that?

**Edit**

I think there is redirection with Go. This does not happen with Python.

**Edit 2**

My question was badly written. I had two problems: 1) the encoding 2) the wrong page returned. I do not know if there are related.

I will open a new thread for the second question.

Comment: Have you tried Windows-1252 encoding? I believe ISO-8559-1 is not supported, but Windows-1252 should work.

Comment: @seesharper Your solution is not working either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument of [NewReader](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html/charset#NewReader) is documented as `contentType` and not as a character encoding. This means it expects the value of the `Content-Type` field in the HTTP header instead. Thus, the proper usage would be:

```
reader, err := charset.NewReader(resp.Body, "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1")
```

And this works perfectly.

Note that if the given `contentType` has no useful charset definition inside it will look at the body itself in order to determine the charset. And while the HTTP header of this page has a clear

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
```

the actual HTML document returned defines a different charset encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

With the wrong setting of `contentType` in your code it will thus take the charset encoding declared wrongly in the HTML.

Comment: Have you compared the result you get in Go with the source code you get in the browser? The problem is still here for me.

Comment: @ItoPakito: I have checked that I get the right data, i.e. proper "fédéral" etc. I don't know what kind of problem exactly is still there for you.

Comment: I see what you mean. You fixed the encoding but there is an issue with the content returned. The last lines should contain something like `window.print( );`. Please, read the edit I have added.

Comment: @ItoPakito: When looking at the source code in the browser you are not looking at the page which was returned by the server but you look at the source code after the script in the page has run. Go does not run any script but it just loads the URL. You better compare this with the output of `curl` and not with the source code view in the browser.

Comment: I have disabled javascript and the source page does not change. It is true that `curl` and Go gives the same results but the Python script gives the same output as the browser does.