# Different page when fetching a page with Python or Curl

Tags: python, http, curl, iso

I am rewriting a software from Python to Go and I have some trouble when requesting a page encoded in `iso-8859-1`.

This code is working:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.bger.ch/ext/eurospider/live/de/php/aza/http/index.php?lang=de&type=show_document&print=yes&highlight_docid=aza://27-01-2016-5A_718-2015")
r.encoding = 'iso-8859-1'
file = open('tmp_python.txt', 'w')
file.write(r.text.strip())
file.close()
```

The last lines are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var imgLoad = imagesLoaded( document.body );
   imgLoad.on( 'always', function( instance ) {
     window.print( );
   } );
</script>


</html>
```

When I do [the same in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60106092/how-to-request-a-page-with-a-specific-charset-in-go), the last lines are:

```
</body>
</html>
```

I thought the problem was in Go. Then I fetched the ressource using `curl`, I also got the wrong result. Therefore, I think the problem is somewhere else.

My browser gets the expected document. So I have added a user agent:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0" https://www.bger.ch/ext/eurospider/live/de/php/aza/http/index.php?lang=de&type=show_document&print=yes&highlight_docid=aza://27-01-2016-5A_718-2015
```

My browser fetches the expected page like the Python script does. This is not the case for `curl` nor for the Go script. What could explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server seems to look at the `User-Agent` field of the request header to decide which content to server. When doing some simple faking you get the same content as Python and the browser do:

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", link, nil)
req.Header.Add("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

I also get this content when doing the curl command you proposed, at least after properly quoting the URL.